# How to keep Celery alive on Heroku?

Tags: python, django, heroku, process, celery

I am trying to run these commands on Heroku:

```
python manage.py celery worker --loglevel=info
python manage.py celery beat
```

i can run them from my terminal, but when i close it the processes stop to run. I probably should change Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn appname.wsgi
celery: python manage.py celery worker --loglevel=info
celery: python manage.py celery beat
```

but I dunno how or if I really should change anything.
How do I keep celery processes running on my heroku app?

Comment: You seen confused about what's running on your local machine vs what's running on Heroku.

Comment: hello @DanielRoseman , ill try to explain again: i know how to make everything to work locally, but i have no idea how to make it run on heroku too

Comment: But you do: by changing your Procfile. What is your question?

Comment: How do I keep celery processes running on my heroku app?

Comment: Have you provisioned dynos? Which pricing model are you using for this app? If you're using the free dynos (new pricing, introduced a couple of weeks ago) you will get a worker for free I think.

Comment: hello @AndréLaszlo i am using free model, I am not sure how should I provision dynos